# How to Flip Edge direction?

Tags: edges, normals, screw-modifier

these **edges** have **different normals** I think.how can I **fix it** so they have the **same normals**? (without converting to curve ...)
please check the blend file. thank you.
[image]

[image]

Answer 1 : for closed shapes, you can turn on **calculate order** in **screw modifier**.
but this is **not working on open shapes**.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looke here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/259611/flipping-vertex-edge-normals-issue

Comment: The top one is correct with the normals facing outwards. For the bottom one, click one of the verts, hit Ctrl-L to select all of it then Alt-N > Flip to flip the normals.

Comment: @JiříHonzák thanks. i was looking for a faster way. i need this for many objects imported from CAD.

Comment: @JohnEason thanks, i already try that. but it's not working.

Comment: You'll need to share the Blend file in that case so that someone can have a look. Share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions on that page.

Comment: @JohnEason thanks for the tip. I uploaded the file.

Comment: If you open the Normals dropdown section at the bottom of the Screw Modifier panel you'll see a Calculate Order and a Flip checkbox. Checking both will correct the normals on both parts of that object.

Comment: @JohnEason thanks. I updated the question.

Comment: It looks as if you have to have both options unchecked for that particular object but I've no idea why. I'm also not sure why you're using a screw modifier to create it in the first place.

Comment: @JohnEason i imported a cad file that contain closed shape for building and open shapes for walls around the building. i use screw modifier and solidify to give the height and thickness of the wall in a procedural way. but because of the wrong direction of the shape, solidify modifier does not work as i expected.

Comment: I don't know python, but it sounds as if a script to search for and extrude objects with just edges upwards would be more suitable for that.

Comment: @JohnEason thanks.